# Robo Gallery Pro plugin only shows tiny photos

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, gallery

I try to insert a gallery plugin with the name "Robo Gallery Pro" to my page, but the result makes my photos too small:

[image: Photos shown too small]

I tried other plugins on my page, and none of them shows the photos in the right way.

I searched my code for mistakes, but I am new to PHP and WordPress. How can I fix this?

Comment: How about contacting the developers of that plugin?

Comment: I try several plugins and don't work. I am sure that I have problem to my code